# Is there any way to persist a Swift closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, persistence

I need to persist a closure but it doesn't seem possible with any persistence methods available in Swift and I can't seem to find any information.

Comment: I guess you should write a virtual machine and translate the "swift code" in runtime if I don't get you wrong. Swift isn't a script language, all the code we wrote should be compiled into machine code. So you have to write a system that can read scripts written in "Swift syntax" and translate them into closures , and this system is indeed a virtual machine.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Given that the closure has to be defined at compile time, there is no need to serialise the closure. Even if there are multiple closures you want to chose from depending on some data value, all you need to store is the value, not the actual closure

Comment: can you maybe post some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the "Code" part of the closure is fixed (compiled) there is no need to persist it, you only need to keep a reference to it with a keyword or some other identifier.  This can be achieved using a dictionary with references to functions for example (i.e. a factory of functions).

What actually needs persistence are the variables that are captured by the closure. This is equivalent to parameters of a function.

So basically, you should probably approach your problem differently and define a set of function keywords and parameter lists.  You can easily persist those and later "execute" the data by passing the parameters to the factory of functions associated with the keywords.